# How do I post to a user's wall with images?

Tags: javascript, facebook

```
function publish(){
  var wallPost = {
    message : "testing...",
    picture: "http://seho.woto.net/fb/cordova_bot.png"
  };
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured');
    } else {
      alert('Post ID: ' + response);
    }
  });
}
```

When I post to the wall with the above function, the post is displayed like this:

[image]

But what I want is something like this:

[image]

So I wonder how I can add images inside the message? How can other apps do that?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to make a post, but upload a photo to the user’s wall instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

If you don’t want to do an actual HTTP upload of the photo data (hard to do from JS), but just have Facebook pull the photo from an URL – then use parameter `url` instead of `source`.